# How can I transcode a Dolby Vision video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I would like to use FFmpeg to take a Dolby Vision video, and output Dolby Vision at the end. I can see that x265 has some flags to pass, so I have made some attempts using that. An example is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -maxrate 89000k -crf 19 -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -an -x265-params vbv-bufsize=89000:vbv-maxrate=89000:dolby-vision-profile=5:hdr-opt=1:colorprim=bt2020:transfer=smpte2084:colormatrix=bt2020nc -f mpegts output.ts
```

This is the MediaInfo output for the original file:

```
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L5@High
HDR format                               : Dolby Vision, Version 1.0, Profile 5, dvhe.05.06, BL+RPU
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
```

While MediaInfo shows it did not preserve the Dolby Vision information in the converted file:

```
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L5@High
Codec ID                                 : 36
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0 (Type 0)
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Writing library                          : x265 3.5+115-7fd02e716:[Windows][GCC 13.2.0][64 bit] 10bit
Encoding settings                        : cpuid=1111039 / frame-threads=3 / numa-pools=12 / wpp / no-pmode / no-pme / no-psnr / no-ssim / log-level=2 / input-csp=1 / input-res=3840x2160 / interlace=0 / total-frames=0 / level-idc=0 / high-tier=1 / uhd-bd=0 / ref=1 / no-allow-non-conformance / repeat-headers / annexb / aud / no-eob / no-eos / hrd / info / hash=0 / temporal-layers=0 / open-gop / min-keyint=23 / keyint=250 / gop-lookahead=0 / bframes=3 / b-adapt=0 / b-pyramid / bframe-bias=0 / rc-lookahead=5 / lookahead-slices=8 / scenecut=0 / no-hist-scenecut / radl=0 / no-splice / no-intra-refresh / ctu=32 / min-cu-size=16 / no-rect / no-amp / max-tu-size=32 / tu-inter-depth=1 / tu-intra-depth=1 / limit-tu=0 / rdoq-level=0 / dynamic-rd=0.00 / no-ssim-rd / no-signhide / no-tskip / nr-intra=0 / nr-inter=0 / no-constrained-intra / strong-intra-smoothing / max-merge=2 / limit-refs=0 / no-limit-modes / me=0 / subme=0 / merange=57 / temporal-mvp / no-frame-dup / no-hme / no-weightp / no-weightb / no-analyze-src-pics / deblock=0:0 / no-sao / no-sao-non-deblock / rd=2 / selective-sao=0 / early-skip / rskip / fast-intra / no-tskip-fast / no-cu-lossless / no-b-intra / no-splitrd-skip / rdpenalty=0 / psy-rd=2.00 / psy-rdoq=0.00 / no-rd-refine / no-lossless / cbqpoffs=0 / crqpoffs=3 / rc=crf / crf=19.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpstep=4 / stats-write=0 / stats-read=0 / vbv-maxrate=89000 / vbv-bufsize=89000 / vbv-init=0.9 / min-vbv-fullness=50.0 / max-vbv-fullness=80.0 / crf-max=0.0 / crf-min=0.0 / ipratio=1.40 / pbratio=1.30 / aq-mode=1 / aq-strength=0.00 / cutree / zone-count=0 / no-strict-cbr / qg-size=32 / no-rc-grain / qpmax=69 / qpmin=0 / no-const-vbv / sar=1 / overscan=0 / videoformat=5 / range=1 / colorprim=2 / transfer=2 / colormatrix=2 / chromaloc=1 / chromaloc-top=0 / chromaloc-bottom=0 / display-window=0 / cll=0,0 / min-luma=0 / max-luma=1023 / log2-max-poc-lsb=8 / vui-timing-info / vui-hrd-info / slices=1 / no-opt-qp-pps / no-opt-ref-list-length-pps / no-multi-pass-opt-rps / scenecut-bias=0.05 / no-opt-cu-delta-qp / no-aq-motion / no-hdr10 / hdr10-opt / no-dhdr10-opt / no-idr-recovery-sei / analysis-reuse-level=0 / analysis-save-reuse-level=0 / analysis-load-reuse-level=0 / scale-factor=0 / refine-intra=0 / refine-inter=0 / refine-mv=1 / refine-ctu-distortion=0 / no-limit-sao / ctu-info=0 / no-lowpass-dct / refine-analysis-type=0 / copy-pic=1 / max-ausize-factor=1.0 / no-dynamic-refine / no-single-sei / no-hevc-aq / no-svt / no-field / qp-adaptation-range=1.00 / scenecut-aware-qp=0conformance-window-offsets / right=0 / bottom=0 / decoder-max-rate=0 / no-vbv-live-multi-pass / no-mcstf / no-sbrc
Color range                              : Full
```

Comment: I don't know about Dolby Vision, but try adding Bitstream Filter: `-bsf:v hevc_metadata=colour_primaries=9:transfer_characteristics=16:matrix_coefficients=9`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that has added some extra fields in the MediaInfo output but it still does not have the "HDR format" part. I have added the MediaInfo output for the original file in case that helps

Comment: According to the [following guide](https://codecalamity.com/encoding-uhd-4k-hdr10-videos-with-ffmpeg/#saving-dolby-vision), it looks like we need an RPU file. According to the guide, it is not supported by FFmpeg, and we have to use `x265-10b` in command line (or `NVEncC` in command line). Please note that I have no experience with Dolby Vision.